# Randomizing a specific group mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have this line of code:

```
$results = mysql_query('
    SELECT * 
    FROM members 
    WHERE category1="Photographers" 
    ORDER BY premium DESC, featured DESC, company ASC');
```

Everything works great, Premium members show up above featured. Featured above regular members, and they are all in alphabetical order. However I want to have featured members show above regular members but randomized and not in alphabetical order. I have tried RAND() but it randomizes all my members, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM members 
WHERE category1="Photographers" 
ORDER BY 
    premium DESC, 
    featured DESC, 
    CASE WHEN featured = 1 THEN RAND() ELSE company END ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CASE in an ORDER BY something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM members 
WHERE category1="Photographers" 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Featured = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Rand()
```